# Making post request with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

In my React application, I have a form with only username and password (later I will add "confirm password" as well), when submitting a request with JSON should be send that contains the email and password in its body.

Password can only be accepted after few checks and if it passes all of those conditions then it will be accepted.

```
render() {
    return (
      <form className="demoForm" onSubmit={this.handleUserInput} >
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={!this.state.formValid}>Sign U p</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

handleUserInput = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value}, () => { this.validateField(name, value) });
    axios.post('****', {
      value
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I am using axios like above, my problem is that I dont know what should be instead of this ****, I am using local host. Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: `'****'` should be a server route that will handle the request that you have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the address you are posting your call to. (i.e. /api/validate_user)

Just on a side note, try separating your actions.

```
 onChangeHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { value, id} = e.target
    this.setState({
        [id]: value
    })
}
```

to update the state and then to submit

```
onSubmitHandler(e) {
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault()
    const { userName, password } = this.state;
    // Do validation of password
    axios.post('/api/validateUser', {
       user: userName,
       password: password
    }).then(e => {
        if(e.success){
            console.log("success")
        }
        else if(e.error) {
            console.log("error logging in")
        }
    })
}
```